# How I can remove the gap between the mosaic image

Tags: gdal, mosaic

I tried to mosaic the 2 Landsat images through 
 (gdal_merge.py stacklayer.tif stacklayer_1.tif -o mosaaic.tiff)

following output come
[image: mosaic image]

How I can remove the gap although there projection is same
[image]

Before running the code both images looks like as above

Comment: What does the imputimages.tif look like? Are you saying you don't want to see the black or that there should be some data inbetween?

Comment: I have input 2 landsat images and want to mosaic them. these two 2 images overlap each other but when I do mosaic the output result is like above image

Comment: How do they look in QGIS (or your favorite GIS viewer)? What coordinate system are they in? Your command only copies/converts inputimages.tif into mosaaic.tiff (mosaic.tif) as there is only one input listed; I can understand obscuring the path for confidentiality but shouldn't there be at least two input images?

Comment: The above image is the viewer in GIS. They are in WGS_1984_UTM_zone_50N. my command is gdalmerge.py stack.tif stack_1.tif -o mosaic.tif

Comment: That is a view of the mosaic, how do they look if you add both source images stack.tif and stack_1.tif to the layout (canvas, map, etc..)?

Comment: 2nd images is the look before mosaic

Comment: What is the sense of this: `gdal_merge.py inputimages.tif -o mosaaic.tiff` ? You merge just ONE image ? If that is wrong, please provide the full command. Edit the Question and add that information! People won't read through all the comments to gather the needed information.

Comment: and could you also add the `gdalinfo` output of stack.tif and stack_1.tif ?

Comment: Picture 1 is the output of mosaic. No I am mosaicing 2 image not single

Comment: Please add **all** information to the question, not only in the comments.

Comment: That is *very* odd, this sort of result should (could) only happen if the images are in different spatial reference models, perhaps try warping first with GDALWarp -t_srs EPSG:32650, but first have a good look at the information output by GDALInfo stack.tif and stack_1.tif, you should get the projection as GDAL sees it and the **bounding boxes** of both images, draw the boxes by coords in your GIS editor and see if the boxes *truly* overlap as *GDAL sees it*; it is possible there is extra georeference information that GDAL doesn't recognize but your viewer does recognize. What viewer is it?

Comment: this viewer is ERDAS IMAGINE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NASA ASP's (https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/asr/groups/intelligent-robotics/ngt/stereo/) dem_mosaic utility? It uses gdal under the hood but takes care of projection and warping on the fly.